# Why use the "best model according to data" in academic research; wildly unrealistic?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, causality, academia

When someone fits a GLM model, it is the "perfect" fit based on the algorithm.

But I find that this is absurd... we are not looking for "the best model", we are looking for the correct one.

Given that you have a very large input space, why would we assume that the best fit model is the real model?

This goes beyond dropping and/or adding variables: once you have chosen your input variables, you basically just have 1 model and crown that to be the truth. In approximations (rather than an exact solution) you *might* have some variation, but then again it is still about optimization. There's absolutely no guarantee that the best model is a realistic one.
A worse scoring model could hold completely different values, but be more realistic.

It seems like everything academic is based on the notion that the best found model is the real one. Where does this assumption come from? I have the feeling that this assumption leads to much bigger problems than any other assumpion. Of course, people like to say "correlation != causation", but that's more or less just agreeing with this. And afterwards, people will still argue that "the theory is in line, and we use this model to prove the evidence". How could you take "evidence from the best model" and reasonably jump to "my theory is proven by the best model". People then use the discussion section to try to bind the result of "quantitative research (best found model)" to their hypothesis, right? This combination of everything sounds very weird to me.

In fact, anyone could argue that their hypothesis is proven by the best fitting model (given the sign is correct). That just seems very strange.

Comment: No serious statistician would claim that a particular model for a certain population or process is the 'right' one. We try to use the best feasible model to explain what can be observed. Often it is convenient (and 'good enough') to model test scores or human heights as normal (ignoring the tiny probability a normal distribution would put on negative values). I guess it was G.E.P. Box who (first) said: "All models are wrong, but some are useful." // If by 'correct' you mean absolute truth described with perfect accuracy, then maybe there is a theology site for this question.

Comment: @BruceET The definition of "best" here can be replaced with "chosen model for a paper / model chosen in production". I guess it is because the expected result is the highest of this model (also using cross validation), but I don't find your answer very satisfying...  "because we can't do any better", "good enough" and "some models might be useful" is not how research results are presented in papers! And also, I feel it is a too generic statement of Box to be addressing this particular part of GLM.

Comment: Simply put: there's an inifinite amount of combinations between coefficients, and we conveniently use the best because it is practical... that just feels wrong. I'm curious to how maximimally different the coeficients in a problem could be, while still being within ~1% of the accuracy of the best fit, but this seems impractical to compute.

Comment: Could you include some citations/evidence for your claims? I've never read an academic paper claiming that their model is *the best*, as opposed to *the best to date*.

Comment: @AlexR. Yea I realize my mistake, I meant "best fit" not best model.

Comment: I'm not going on a witch hunt for papers, but of course the goal in every paper is to convince the reader that the results are realistic (given a lot of assumptions). And that includes a "best fit" (the one that optimizes e.g. R2). There's no paper that will say: "we scrambled some coefficients together that seemed reasonable". But we cannot change how a GLM works if we would want a "very different outcome but still within reasonable error margin of a best fit".

Comment: We would earlier collect more data, think of mistakes in preprocessing etc, rather than think "well, perhaps a suboptimal GLM solution might match my hypothesis and the true parameters".

Comment: I guess this is the point: you cannot defend a suboptimal fit (while this might in fact be "the truth"). On what grounds would you be able to defend it?

Answer (score 3):

> we are not looking for "the best model", we are looking for the correct one.

No, we aren't. We are indeed looking for the "best model", not the correct one.

I recommend [Burnham & Anderson, *Model Selection and Multi-Model Inference*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008UBJ0VQ). They advocate for the AIC precisely on the grounds that asymptotically it will find the model among our candidate models that is *closest* to the true data generating process (DGP), even if the DGP is not among our candidates.

And this is all the defense we need. We have zero chance of finding the correct model (B&A refer to "tapering effect sizes"), but we *can* find a reasonable approximation, where "reasonable" depends on the DGP, on prior theory and, importantly, on sample size, and then proceed to learn from that approximation, where learning can be either one of inference, prediction or anything else.

This is completely mainstream in applied statistics. If anyone publishes a paper claiming that model *M* that they chose is the *correct* model to describe some reality, then the reviewer let one slip through.